# Hartshorne EX. III.10.3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> A morphism $f: X\to Y$ of schemes of finite type over $k$ is etale if it is smooth of
>   relative dimension $0$. It is unramified if for every $x\in X$, letting $y = f(x)$, we have
>   $m_y\cdot\mathcal{O}_x = m_x$, and $k(x)$ is a separable algebraic extension of $k(y)$. Show that the
>   following conditions are equivalent:
>
> (i) $f$ is etale;
>
> (ii) $f$ is flat, and $\Omega_{X/Y}= 0$;
>
> (iii) $f$ is flat and unramified.

To show (i) and (ii) are equivalent: recall $f$ is smooth of relative dimension $0$ (i.e. etale) if

(1) $f$ is flat;

(2) if $X'\subset X$ and $Y'\subset Y$ are irreducible components such that $f(X')\subset Y'$, then $\dim X' = \dim Y'$;

(3) For any $x\in X$, $\dim_{k(x)} \Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)=0$.

I wonder why $f$ is etale implies $\Omega_{X/Y}=0$: I know if $X$ is integal then $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is locally free, but here we don't have $X$ integal, then how to guarantee $ \Omega_{X/Y}$ doesn't have torsion? More precisely, I think $\dim \Omega_{X/Y}\otimes k(x)=0$ can only guarantee $ \Omega_{X/Y}$ has rank $0$, how to see it doesn't have torsion.

For the converse part, I know $f(X')$ is irreducible in $Y$ but I think I need some facts to deduce $\dim X' = \dim Y'$, can you give me some ideas?

For (2) and (3) are equivalent, since it refers to the separable algebraic extension, I think we need to use II.8.6.A:

> Let $K$ be a finitely generated extension field of afield $k$. Then
>   $\dim_K\Omega_{K/k}\ge\text{tr.d.} K/k$, and equality holds if and only if $K$ is separably
>   generated over $k$.

But I think in order to get $K$, we need $X$ to be integral, and $\Omega_{K/k}$ is corresponding to the stalk of $\Omega_{X/k}$ at the generic point. However, I can't go further.

Comment: The dimension in (3) is a $k(x)$-vector space dimension. (There is a typo in (ii), \Omega for \O.)

Comment: Your first confusion will be resolved if you can show that $(\Omega_{X/k})_x=0$ for all $x\in X$. This follows from Nakayama's lemma since $\Omega_{X/k}$ is  a coherent sheaf on $X$ and any basis of the fiber $\Omega_{X/k}\otimes k(x)$ lifts to a  basis of $(\Omega_{X/k})_x.$ 
The second is more involved, essentially use the localisation properties of the differentials and note that you can always replace the scheme by its reduction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strategy is inappropriate to this question. This first part is a straightforwards application of Nakayama's lemma: $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is coherent, so $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x$ is a finitely generated module over the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$. Then the statement about the dimension is the same as $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} k(x)= (\Omega_{X/Y})_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}/\mathfrak{m}_x = (\Omega_{X/Y})_x/\mathfrak{m}_x(\Omega_{X/Y})_x=0$, or $\mathfrak{m}_x(\Omega_{X/Y})_x=(\Omega_{X/Y})_x$, so by Nakayama, this means that $(\Omega_{X/Y})_x=0$. This means that the stalk of $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is zero at every point, or that $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is the zero sheaf. So we've shown (i) implies (ii).

The rest of the argument will make frequent use of some basic facts about  $\Omega_{X/Y}$:

> - **Hartshorne II.8.2A**: For a ring map $A\to B$ and a base extension $A\to A'$ which gives a ring map $A' \to B':= B\otimes_A A'$, we have $\Omega_{B'/A'}=\Omega_{B/A}\otimes_B B'$.
> - **Hartshorne II.8.2A**: For $S\subset B$ multiplicatively closed, $S^{-1}\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{S^{-1}B/A}$.
> - If $R\subset A$ is multiplicatively closed and $R$ maps to invertible elements of $B$, then $\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{B/R^{-1}A}$. (Proof: apply the Leibniz rule to $1=f(s)f(s)^{-1}$.)
> - For any surjective morphism of rings $A\to B$, we have $\Omega_{B/A}=0$.
> - **Hartshorne II.8.3A**: If $A\to B \to C$ are maps of rings, we have a natural exact sequence of $C$-modules $$\Omega_{B/A}\otimes_B C \to \Omega_{C/A} \to \Omega_{C/B}\to 0$$
> - **Hartshorne II.8.7A**: Let $A$ be a local ring with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ containing a field $k$ isomorphic to it's residue field. Then there is an isomorphism $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\to \Omega_{B/k}\otimes_B k$.
> - If $A\to B$ is a ring map with $\Omega_{B/A}=0$, then the induced map on reductions $A_{red}\to B_{red}$ also has $\Omega_{B_{red}/A_{red}}=0$.

The final statement comes from an application of II.8.3A to the sequences of ring maps $A\to A_{red}\to B_{red}$ and $A\to B\to B_{red}$: the first gives you that $\Omega_{B_{red}/A}\cong \Omega_{B_{red}/A_{red}}$ since $\Omega_{A_{red}/A}=0$ as the ring map $A\to A_{red}$ is surjective, and the second gives you that $0=\Omega_{B/A}\otimes_B B_{red}$ surjects on to $\Omega_{B_{red}/A}\cong\Omega_{B_{red}/A_{red}}$ because $\Omega_{B_{red}/B}=0$.

To show (ii) implies (i), the fact that our map is flat and of finite type implies it is open because of exercise III.9.1. Let $Y'$ be an irreducible component of $Y$ and let $X'$ be an irreducible component of $X$ which maps in to $Y'$. Now take an affine open $Y''$ of $Y'$ which is open in $Y$ and some affine open $X''$ of $X'$ open in $X$ mapping in to it. As our map is open, the image of $X''$ in $Y''$ is open and thus dense, so the generic point of $X''$ maps to the generic point of $Y''$ (further, this map of generic points is exactly the same as the map of generic points one gets with $X'\to Y'$).

By the final quoted statement above and the fact that taking reductions does not change dimensions nor the fact that the generic point of $X''$ maps to the generic point of $Y''$, we may replace $X''$ and $Y''$ by their reductions while maintaining their dimensions and $\Omega_{X''/Y''}=0$. Now look at the map on generic points: by the localization property above, we get that the module of differentials associated to the induced map of fraction fields vanishes, so by II.8.6a, we have that these fraction fields are of the same transcendence degree and thus $X''$ and $Y''$ (and therefore $X'$ and $Y'$) have the same dimension. (Explicitly, if $A\to B$ is the map of domains induced by $X''\to Y''$, then let $S=B\setminus \{0\}$ and let $R=A\setminus\{0\}$, so $0=S^{-1}\Omega_{B/A}=\Omega_{S^{-1}B/A}=\Omega_{S^{-1}B/R^{-1}A}$, and this last module is the module of differentials associated to the induced map on fraction fields.)

To show that (ii) and (iii) are the same, we argue affine-locally, which lets us treat this as an algebra problem. To be clear: we want to show that a finite type map of $k$-algebras $f:A\to B$ has $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ iff it is unramified. By the localization properties above, it is not hard to see that this is equivalent to the stalk-local problem: if we have a finite type local map of local rings $A\to B$, then unramified is equivalent to $\Omega_{B/A}=0$.

Suppose $A,B$ are local rings with maximal ideals $\mathfrak{m},\mathfrak{n}$ and residue fields $E,F$ respectively and $f:A\to B$ is a local ring map of finite type between them. If we assume unramified, then by base change we get that $\Omega_{B/A}\otimes_A E = \Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/E}$, and as $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ by assumption, we get that this last module is just the module of differentials associated to the map of residue fields $E\to F$. By assumption, this is separable algebraic, so by II.8.6a we have that it vanishes, and then by Nakayama we get that $\Omega_{B/A}=0$ as requested.

For the reverse direction, we'll show that if either the conditions $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ or "$F$ is a separable extension of $E$" is violated, then $\Omega_{B/A}\neq 0$. Start with the extension of fields: write $E\to B/\mathfrak{m}B \to F$, and applying II.8.3A, we get the following exact sequence.

$$ \Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/E} \otimes_{B/\mathfrak{m}B} F \to \Omega_{F/E}\to \Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/F}\to 0$$

The final term vanishes because the ring map $B/\mathfrak{m}B\to B/\mathfrak{n}=F$ is surjective, so the first map is a surjection. In particular, if the extension of fields $E\subset F$ is not algebraic separable then by II.8.6a we get the middle term is nonzero, then the left term must be nonzero, and as $\Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/E}\cong \Omega_{B/A}\otimes_A E$, we get $\Omega_{B/A}\neq 0$.

There are two ways we can fail to have $\mathfrak{m}B=\mathfrak{n}$ - either $\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}B}$ is equal to $\mathfrak{n}$ or not. If they're not equal, II.8.3a applied to $E\to B/\mathfrak{m}B\to B/\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}B}$ combined with the observation that $B/\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}B}$ has a fraction field which is of positive transcendence degree over $E$ gives that $\Omega_{B/A}\neq 0$ similarly to the above conclusion.

In the other case, $\sqrt{\mathfrak{m}B}=\mathfrak{n}$ but $\mathfrak{m}B\neq \mathfrak{n}$, we have that $B/\mathfrak{m}B$ is Artinian and thus finite-dimensional as an $E$-vector space. Let $K$ be an algebraic closure of $A/\mathfrak{m}$. Then $B/\mathfrak{m}B \otimes_{E} K$ is again Artinian and a finite product of Artinian local rings with $K$ as their residue field. As $B/\mathfrak{m}B$ has a nilpotent element, $(B/\mathfrak{m}B)\otimes_{E} K$ has a nilpotent element and there exists some local ring factor $B'\subset K\otimes_{E} B/\mathfrak{m}B$ with nonzero nilpotent maximal ideal $\mathfrak{q}$. By II.8.7, we have that $\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q}^2\cong \Omega_{B'/K}\otimes_{B'} K$ and thus the RHS is nonzero, and so $\Omega_{B'/K}$ is nonzero by Nakayama. As $\Omega_{B'/K}$ is a localization of $\Omega_{((B/\mathfrak{m}B)\otimes_{E} K)/K}\cong \Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/E}\otimes_{E} K$ at a maximal ideal, $\Omega_{(B/\mathfrak{m}B)/E}$ is nonzero and we are done.

---

The equivalence of (ii) and (iii) seems like kind of a pain to me if you're trying to do it with just the tools Hartshorne has available at this point. I prefer the [StacksProject definitions](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GH) which define all of these things through standard smooth/etale/unramified ring maps, which makes everything a bit more straightforwards.

Comment: Why is an affine open of $Y′$ which is open in $Y$? I think an open subset of  closed subpsace might not be open in the ambient space. Do you mean we select this affine open of $Y'$  s.t. it is also open in $Y$?

Comment: $Y$ has finitely many irreducible components because it is noetherian. So the union of all but one irreducible component in $Y$ is closed, and it's complement is an open subset of exactly one irreducible component. Since the affine open subschemes form a basis for the topology on $Y$, there is some affine open contained in the aforementioned open set, and thus we have produced an affine open of $Y'$ which is also open in $Y.

Comment: For the module of differentials associated to the induced map of fraction fields, I think you mean the  $S^{-1}\Omega_{\mathcal{O}_{X'}/f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y'}}=\Omega_{(\mathcal{O}_{X'})_p/(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y'})_{f(p)}}=\Omega_{K(X')/K(Y')}$, where $p$ is the generic point. But I think $\Omega_{(\mathcal{O}_{X'})_p}=K(X')$ if $X'$ is integral, however here we don't have this assumption. Also I am not sure if $(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{Y'})_{f(p)}=K(Y')$ for the $f^{-1}$.

Comment: You're right, I had explicitly taken care of irreducible but not reduced. Fortunately, this may be solved without too much trouble. I have updated the post to include this reasoning and to make some minor formatting adjustments. Please let me know if this addresses your concerns.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. I have two more questions. (1) Is that because of the localization commutes with the colimit, so we have $(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(p)}=(\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(p)}$? (2) You picked up open affine for $X',Y'$, but where did you use them?

Comment: I used the open affines to reduce to an algebra problem. If you have a map of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec} B=X\to Y=\operatorname{Spec} A$, then $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is the sheaf associated to the $B$-module $\Omega_{B/A}$. Now everything about computing stalks is standard: the stalk at $(0)$, the generic point, is just the localization at $(0)$, and we can use the results about how $\Omega_{B/A}$ behaves with localization. (I'm a little unclear about what you're actually asking about in (1) - can you be more specific?)

Comment: I am asking if $(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(p)}=\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(p)}$. My thought is since we use colimit to define for the sheaf $(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y)$  and colimit commutes with localization, so we $(f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y)_{f(p)}=\mathcal{O}_{Y,f(p)}$.

Comment: So you just see $X'$ as Spec$B$ and $Y'$ as Spec$A$?

Comment: The stuff about $f^{-1}$ and stalks follows directly from the definition and is correct (though I do not see it's relevance here). As for the stuff about $X'$, I had missed some notation - I want to pick $Y''\subset Y'$ an affine open which is open in $Y$ and $X''\subset X'$ an affine open of $X$ which maps in to $Y''$, but I had not made this sufficiently clear in the answer (I just made an edit which deals with this). Then we can make the shift to the algebra side.

Comment: I think by a sheaf is zero iff its stalks are zero and II.8.2.A, we can only show if $\Omega_{X/Y}=0$, then  $\Omega_{X'/Y}=0$ and $\Omega_{X''/Y}=0$, how to deduce to the $\Omega_{X'/Y'}=0$ and $\Omega_{X''/Y''}=0$?

Comment: Consult remark II.8.9.2: if $\operatorname{Spec} B =U$ is an open affine subset of $X$ and $\operatorname{Spec} A= V$ is an open affine subset of $Y$ such that $f(U)\subset V$, then $\Omega_{X/Y}|_U\cong \Omega_{U/V}\cong \widetilde{\Omega_{B/A}}$, and all of these identifications are natural. As a generalization, for any open $U\subset X$ mapping in to any open $V\subset Y$, we have that $\Omega_{X/Y}|_U\cong\Omega_{U/V}$, so there is no need to worry.

Comment: Sorry,  I have one more question regarding the stalk of the relative differential sheaf. I know for the structure sheaf over $X=Spec A$, the stalk at $p\in Spec A$, we have $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}=(A\setminus p)^{-1}\mathcal{O}_{X}(X)=A_p$. But for the relative differential sheaf, why do you get $(\Omega_{Spec A/Spec B})_p=(A\setminus p)^{-1}\Omega_{Spec A/Spec B}(Spec A)$? I think it may not be true for any sheaf. And I think II.8.2.A just tells us t $(\Omega_{Spec A/Spec B})_p=(A\setminus p)^{-1}\Omega_{Spec A/Spec B}(Spec A)=\Omega_{ A_p/ B}$, so it doesn't help.

Comment: This is a basic property of quasicoherent sheaves. If you have a quasicoherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$, it's restriction to an open subset is again quasicoherent (as this property is local), and has the same stalks (any restriction of any sheaf to any open subset has the same stalks). Thus restricting to an affine open $\operatorname{Spec} R$, our sheaf is $\mathcal{F}\cong\widetilde{M}$ for some $R$-module $M$, and the stalk at a point $p$ is just $M_p=(\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec} R))_p$. Since $\Omega_{X/Y}$ is quasicoherent, all of this works for it.